# Fontawesome icons not showing

Tags: xetex, fontawesome

I'm recompiling my CV after updating a few details. I use a few icons throughout which have previously worked with no issues, but are not showing anymore.

I get no warnings or errors. I've provided a simplified version of the code below which also compiles with no errors or warnings, but does not show the icons either:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\faLinkedin
hello

\end{document}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest (4.3)  version of the fonts? I compile without any problem (even with `pdflatex` now).

Comment: When I try to compile this (with xelatex in MacTeX 2015), I get the error message `fontspec error: "font-not-found"`, even though `fontawesome` is included with MacTex 2015. I don't understand why. (Also, you don't need to load `fontspec`, since it's loaded with `fontawesome`, and it's not clear to me what `graphicx` is doing in your MWE.)

Comment: I left graphicx in by accident, removing that from the MWE still results in the icons not loading. I have loaded fontspec as that is used elsewhere in my full document - but again removing from the MWE still results in icons not loading @Sverre

Comment: Okay so @Bernard I've confirmed that I have the latest version of the fonts.

Comment: Interestingly compiling with LuaLatex rather than XeLaTeX works for the MWE, but my full CV won't compile with LuaLatex. Does this help diagnose?

Comment: Not for me. Try installing the font (.otf)  as a system font.

Comment: Done and done, no change.

Comment: I can also compile with lualatex, but not with xelatex (the latter gives `font-not-found` error). My guess is that it's not coincidental that both @Ashley and I don't get the right result with xelatex (I get an error, @Ashley doesn't get the symbol), whereas it works with lualatex. It would probably help if more details were added about the software you're compiling with and your OS.

Comment: No problem with  lualatex, xelatex and even pdflatex. I'm on Windows 7+MiKTeX, fontawesome v. 4.3

Comment: I'm running MiKTeX and TeXnicCenter on WIndows 10. Everything is fully up to date.

Comment: Does the problem persist with the last `fontawesome` package release (4.4.0)?

Answer (score 3):

If compiling with `XeLaTeX` then `fontspec` package must be included. An example using this method in the modern cv resume:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}




\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resum\`e title} 
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}   
\homepage{www.johndoe.com} 
\social[linkedin]{john.doe} 
\social[twitter]{jdoe}      
\social[github]{jdoe}       

\moderncvicons{awesome}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\faLinkedin \, hello
or 
\faLinkedinSign \,  hello 

\faTwitter

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I can only get fontawesome printed using pdfLatex writing the \faicon inside a Tikz node!

```
\tikz \node[scale=2] at (0,0) {\faBalanceScale};
```